# Keystore file does not exist: /root/.android/debug.keystore for ubuntu

Tags: android, phonegap-plugins, google-plus, keytool

Need google+ sign in for my phonegap application for that I want to generate Certificate SHA-1.I run 
**keytool -exportcert -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore**

the command to generate Android Signing Certificate SHA-1, but it gave an error
 **Keystore file does not exist: /root/.android/debug.keystore**

so I search for that file using **find ~ -name "debug.keystore"** but my search result is empty.

I also tried below command 
keytool -genkey -alias myKey -keystore store.jks
keytool -selfcert -alias myKey -keystore store.jks

but i didn't found Android Signing Certificate SHA-1

Answer (score 1):

`keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

Try this command. Your debug keystore is always present in `/home/<username>/.android` and `~` is just a shorthand for `/home/<username>`.

If your SDK is installed properly, there should be no issues in running that command. Otherwise, we'll need some more information to find and fix the issue.

If PhoneGap/Meteor has its own set of android bundles, you might want to try something on these lines

`keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.meteor/android_bundle/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the debug certificate, just create a new certificate by following this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html) and use it to sign your debug and release versions of the app.

Comment: This should have been a comment instead.